# CSS transition hover (h1 inside a div seems not to work properly)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a slight problem with css transition. On my website, I have a div, and in that div is a h1.

Here's the css code.

```
#inner1 {
    background-image: url("rsz_astromenu1.jpg");
    height: 333px;
    width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#inner1:hover {
    font-size: 50px;
    transition: font-size 1s linear;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

I want to animate the opacity (from 0.5 to 1) and font-size (from 10px to 50px).
However, when I hover my mouse over that div, the opacity is nicely transitioned, but the text just changes the size instantly. So the hover seems to work and change the font-size, why is transition omitted?

If I make it #inner1 h1:hover, the transition works properly but only when I hover over the text. And I want the font-size transition when I hover over that div.

I tried to work around the problem and write a JS script for enlarging the text.

Here's what I came up with. I'll paste all the HTML content as well since there's not much of it.

However, this is not really smooth, I've gone as far as to incrementing only 0.09px every millisecond, but it still looks bumpy and also sends hundreds of unnecessary commands to the browser, right?

How can I solve that problem? Either with CSS or JS?
Thanks in advance ;).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Gallery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
        <div id="middle">
        <div id="inner1" class="hover-menu">
            <h1 id="astro-h1" class="hover-menu">Astrofotografia</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="inner2"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script>

        var JSinner1 = document.getElementById("inner1");
        var JSastroh1 = document.getElementById("astro-h1")
        JSastroh1.style.fontSize = "16px";


        var textBigger = function() {
            var newSize = parseFloat(JSastroh1.style.fontSize) + 0.009 + "px";
            window.setInterval(textBigger, 1)
            if (parseFloat(newSize) < 60) {

                JSastroh1.style.fontSize = newSize;
                console.log(newSize);
            }
        }
        JSinner1.addEventListener("mouseover", textBigger)




        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple, the problem is your `:hover`selector, as you are adding two transitions properties, the last one is overwriting the previous one. In order to make this work, just add this to that rule:

```
transition: opacity 1s linear, font-size 1s linear;
```

Or you can use

```
transition: all 1s linear;
```

Comment: Oh. My. God. I spent hours figuring this out and wondering why it does not work. The answer was so simple. Thanks a lot ;).

Comment: I'm glad I could help, when you face this kind of issues, use Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug so you can see if your styles are being overwritten by another selector

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting one transition with another. Try with

```
transition: font-size 1s linear,opacity 1s linear;
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
transition: font-size 1s linear;
transition: opacity 1s linear;
```

use `all`

```
transition: all 1s linear;
```

or merge the two into one  `transition: font-size 1s linear,opacity 1s linear;`

```css
#inner1 {
    background-image: url("rsz_astromenu1.jpg");
    height: 333px;
    width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#inner1:hover {
    font-size: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="inner1">
  <h1> Some text </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Overall the all property should not use in any cases. It might cause really bad freezes at mobile devices and older pc/laptops. Instead of doing that he should use double transition  property: transition: opacity 1s, font-size 1s;

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style media="screen">
            #inner1 {
                background-image: url("rsz_astromenu1.jpg");
                height: 333px;
                width: 500px;
                display: inline-block;
                opacity: 0.5;
                font-size: 10px;
                transition: opacity 1s linear, font-size 1s linear;
            }
            #inner1:hover {
                font-size: 50px;
                opacity: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="middle">
                <div id="inner1" class="hover-menu">
                    <h1 id="astro-h1" class="hover-menu">Astrofotografia</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="inner2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```